# Generate package download script using terminal

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I connect to the internet in Windows using a Vodafone GPRS connection. I don't know how to configure it on Ubuntu, so my Ubuntu OS cannot be online. Hence repository updates and software updates are difficult.

So I had been browsing the internet for a solution for 3 months now. I found the solution to this problem by manually adding repositories and then generating a package download script using synaptics. I was happy using GNOME desktop.

But the recent version of Ubuntu is using Unity and by default Synaptic is not installed.

Could you provide me a solution for this? My main concern is that I can manually add repositories but how can I generate the download script using the terminal? This is giving me headache!